# PostgreSQL simple query with repeated function calls

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 9.1.1 running in a shared hosting environment and I'm running this query:

```
SELECT a.id,
CASE WHEN a.idpai IS NULL THEN a.nome
ELSE concat(a.nome, ' (', b.nome, ')')
END AS nome, a.idpai
FROM localidade a
LEFT OUTER JOIN localidade b ON a.idpai = b.id
WHERE a.idcidade = :idcidade AND normalizar(
    CASE WHEN a.idpai IS NULL THEN a.nome
    ELSE concat(a.nome, ' (', b.nome, ')')
    END
) LIKE normalizar(:nome)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN normalizar(
    CASE WHEN a.idpai IS NULL THEN a.nome
    ELSE concat(a.nome, ' (', b.nome, ')')
    END
) LIKE substring(normalizar(:nome) from 2) THEN 1
ELSE 2
END, a.nome, b.nome
LIMIT 15
```

The performance is pretty good, the query returns in less than 50ms. Though, I'm repeating this part 3 times inside the query:

```
CASE WHEN a.idpai IS NULL THEN a.nome
ELSE concat(a.nome, ' (', b.nome, ')')
END
```

I believe this reduces the maintainability of the query and is not DRY at all. What is the recommended way to handle that? Should I create a function in my schema solely for this query? Or just store it in a variable and concatenate into the query in my back end before sending it over to the db server? Or is there any better way around?

I believe what this query does isn't the main point here, but just to give some background:

The `localidade` table may or may not have a relation with itself  through the `idpai` which references a "parent" register. Assuming this table format:

```
id | nome | idpai
 1 | foo  |
 2 | bar  |   1
```

So if the query placeholder `:nome` contains `%foo%`, it will return:

```
id | nome       | idpai
 1 | foo        |
 2 | bar (foo)  |   1
```

The `ORDER BY` clause is just to display results which the query parameter matches the beginning of the returned row's `name` before those who don't - `SUBSTRING('%foo%' FROM 2)` returns `foo%` -, and then the matching and not matching groups are ordered by `a.nome` and `b.nome` ASC as the SQL shows.

`normalizar` is a `STABLE` function that takes a string as parameter and calls `LOWER()` and removes accentuation returning the new string, so I can perform case-insensitive and accent-insensitive string comparison. Similar to [`unaccent`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/unaccent.html) which I couldn't properly apply on my use case due to some encoding problems (page is UTF8 and DB is latin1, if I convert the UTF8 to latin1 solely on the back end I'll have broken UTF8 pages; well this has been solved with the function above and is off-topic).

`idcidade` is just a foreign key which I use to reduce the result set to less than 0.1% of the table. Hence performance isn't really an issue in this specific case.

My real question is, does calling `CASE` multiple times passing the exact same parameters have an impact on performance? I assume the result from `CASE` should be `STABLE` and the query will be optimized automatically then. If that's the case, I can store part of the query into a variable on my back end and build the query string using that. Otherwise, if calling `CASE` multiple times in the same query with the same arguments affects performance, should I create a `STABLE` function for it then or what's the correct approach to this? Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few additional simplifications:

```
SELECT a.id
      ,concat(a.nome, ' (' || b.nome || ')') AS nome
      ,a.idpai
FROM   localidade a
LEFT   JOIN localidade b ON a.idpai = b.id
WHERE  a.idcidade = :idcidade
AND    normalizar(concat(a.nome, ' (' || b.nome || ')'))
       LIKE ('%' || normalizar(:nome) || '%')
ORDER  BY (normalizar(concat(a.nome, ' (' || b.nome || ')'))
           LIKE (normalizar(:nome))  || '%') DESC NULLS LAST
       ,2
LIMIT  15;
```

- [`right(x, -1)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) would be a little simpler and faster than `substring(x from 2)`. But if you follow my advice below you don't need either.
- If you use this query in a prepared statement of function, and you know the search term is never anchored (always `%` around the term - `%foo%`), then it will be faster to use explicit placeholder. Let the planner know, the pattern *always* starts with `%`, so the query plan can be optimized.
- You can just `ORDER BY` the boolean result of an expression. No need for a case statement. `FALSE` (0) sorts before `TRUE` (1) sorts before `NULL`.
  I added `NULLS LAST` to get 100% identical behaviour like your original with descending order. Consider this [**SQLfiddle** demonstrating the effect](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/564).
- I also `ORDER BY` the *positional parameter* `2` to simplify the syntax. Won't make the query faster, just shorter.
- One thing to consider: If `a.idpai IS NOT NULL` that doesn't necessarily mean `b.nome IS NOT NULL`, so the original and the simplified `concat()` version are not identical if `b.nome` can be `NULL`.
- I would make the function `normalizar` `IMMUTABLE`, since the result is always the same for the same input. Probably won't make a difference for this query, though. Both `STABLE` and `IMMUTABLE` function can be optimized by the query planner.
- Some other minor syntax simplifications *just to demonstrate possibilities*. Like .. `~~` is a Postgres operator for the SQL standard `LIKE`. (Niether is faster, `~~` is just shorter but non-standard. Note the slight difference in operator precedence. You may have to change parenthesis since `~~` (or `~~*`, `!~~`, `!~~*`) binds stronger than `LIKE` (or `ILIKE`, `NOT LIKE`, `NOT ILIKE`).

If your tables are big and you really want fast - like **several orders of magnitude faster** than what you have -  then create a **materialized view** (read [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34326/aggregating-statistics-from-child-rows/34458#34458) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283979/postgresql-script-execution-every-night/10285480#10285480)) with a **trigram GIN or GiST index** to support non-anchored `LIKE` searches. Read [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql/10696#10696) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856).

Comment: Thanks for your throughout answer. Many of your answers in SO helped me in the past as well and I'm grateful for that. On topic now, there is no advantage in using `~~` instead of `LIKE` besides the reduced characters, right? In that case the more verbose form `LIKE` is technically more maintainable when members of your team do not have as much PGSQL experience. I forgot to mention that `b.nome` cannot be `null`, my bad. Some things I'm not 100% sure: does `NULLS LAST` make a difference? It seems to be the default. Also does positional parameter 2 correspond to the 2nd column in the SELECT?

Comment: And 2 more serious issues: running `~~` in the `WHERE` results in an "ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text", which doesn't happen using LIKE ([simplified sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5c75e/7)), and one last thing, your `concat(a.nome, ' (', b.nome, ')')` will display `a.nome's value ()` when `b.nome` is `null` - not showing empty brackets  when `b.nome` is `null` was the main point of the question. Thanks for the time to provide your answer and insights though.

Comment: Sorry for the number of questions, but I can only find documentation on positional parameters when it is inside of a SQL function. Weird thing is, the documentation says that double tildes are equivalent to LIKE ([link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html)) but it fails in the fiddle's `WHERE`. Weird.

Comment: Oh the issue with ~~ was probably due to operator precedence, `~~ ('%' || normalizar(:nome)  || '%')` works. At least this shows that these are not 100% equivalent apparently.

Comment: Apart from the issue with empty brackets when `b.nome` is `null`, your answer does not account for ordering by matches starting with the queried string first. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3872a/1

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: **`LIKE`**: ~~ was `just to demonstrate possibilities`. Neither is faster. As you found out yourself: the only difference is in [operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE), you may need parens with `~~`. I should have mentioned that. `~~` is just shorter for ad-hoc queries. I wouldn't use it in stored code.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep these possibilities in mind. +1 for these. Can't give an accept as your query unfortunately breaks the two main goals of my original query.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: **concat()**: I fixed that. Transformed the expression to avoid empty `()` and added the missing `|| '%'` in the `ORDER BY`. Now it should do what you were looking for. Also added clarification for `LIKE` and put it back in the query as that is the better option, generally. And I added an SQLfiddle demo to better explain `ORDER BY <bool> DESC NULLS LAST`. Also consider your [updated SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3872a/3) demonstrating the now working `ORDER BY`. Sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: No problem. `=]` I've never had a too deep involvement with PostgreSQL but my logic thinking never failed me - with your explanation and fiddle the `DESC NULLS LAST` is crystal clear! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I think this part:

```
CASE WHEN a.idpai IS NULL THEN a.nome
ELSE concat(a.nome, ' (', b.nome, ')')
END AS nome
```

Can be replaced with:

```
CONCAT(a.nome,  ' (' || b.nome || ')') AS nome
```

If b.nome is NULL, then "' (' || b.nome || ')'" will also be NULL (concatenating strings using '||' with NULL values will result in NULL. CONCAT() ignore null values, so will return only a.none in this case

In other words: if b.nome is present, it will output "a.nome (b.nome)", otherwise "a.nome"

You can test it yourself, here's my sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/744/0

Also, you can try to use a subselect to prevent having to repeat this CONCAT;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a9571/7/0

I haven checked if this improves performance, but it reduces the amount of repeated code and may be better maintainable

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I've read about the side effect of `||`ing with `NULL` before but never thought of taking advantage of it. Brilliant solution.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Glad I could help!